# Se puede remplazar una 'Raw String' por otra una vez impresa?

Tags: c++, string, str-replace

Tengo tres strings de tipo Raw:

```
string wawe1 = R"(
              ^                       ^         ^
          ^   |           ^           |         |
          |   |     ^     |         ^ |   ^     |
          |   |     |     | ^       | |   |   ^ |
          |   |   ^ |   ^ | |       | | ^ |   | |
          |   |   | |   | | | ^   ^ | | | | ^ | |
          | ^ |   | | ^ | | | | ^ | | | | | | | |
          | | | ^ | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
         ++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++)";
string wawe2 = R"(
                    ^         ^       ^
                    |     ^   |   ^   |
            ^       |     |   |   |   |     ^   ^
            |       | ^   |   | ^ |   | ^   |   |
          ^ |   ^   | |   |   | | |   | |   |   |
          | |   |   | |   |   | | |   | | ^ | ^ |
          | |   | ^ | |   | ^ | | | ^ | | | | | |
          | | ^ | | | | ^ | | | | | | | | | | | |
          | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
         ++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++)";
string wawe3 = R"(
                        ^       ^       ^
              ^   ^     |       |       |     ^
              |   |     |       |   ^   |     |
            ^ |   |     |     ^ |   |   |     |
            | |   |     | ^   | | ^ |   | ^   |
          ^ | |   |   ^ | |   | | | |   | | ^ | ^
          | | | ^ |   | | |   | | | |   | | | | |
          | | | | |   | | |   | | | | ^ | | | | |
          | | | | | ^ | | | ^ | | | | | | | | | |
         ++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++)";
```

Y así las ejecuto:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            cout << wawe1 << 'r' << flush;
            Sleep(1000);
            cout << wawe2 << '\r' << flush;
            Sleep(1000);
            cout << wawe3 << '\r' << flush;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Pero no consigo el efecto que quiero, quisiera que se vayan sustituyendo una por otra, para darle un efecto de movimiento, en lugar de eso consigo que se imprima una detrás de otra.

Es posible hacer lo que busco?

Comment: Que sea `raw` no importa aquí para nada. Lo que pides no se puede hacer en C++ *puro*, depende del sistema operativo empleado. En Windows, lo mas fácil sería usar `conio.h`.

Comment: Busca la librería `rlutil.h`. Es una especie de versión moderna de `conio.h` con la ventaja de que también funciona para Linux. Btw, la función que puedes usar para simular el movimiento es `gotoxy`.

Comment: @Trauma Que parte de la librería podría utilizar?, o cómo lo busco?

Comment: @Xam X y Y son las coordenadas de la consola?, cómo consigo las coordenadas de mi texto?

Comment: Si quieres substituir cadenas, usa el operador de asignación (`waveX = waveY`). Si quieres imprimir las cadenas sobre las anteriores, primero deberás borrar la pantalla.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus no podía borrar la pantalla porque tenía datos impresos anteriormente y no quería eliminarlos. Termine usando el gotoxy y fue lo mejor. Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución a mi problema fue seguir usando las RAW strings y remplazarlo por otro mediante la fila donde se encontraba, para conseguir las coordenadas fue mediante prueba y error:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}
```

Así lo implemente;

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    gotoxy(1,27); cout << wawe1 << '\r' << flush;
    Sleep(500);
    gotoxy(1,27);cout << wawe2 << '\r' << flush;
    Sleep(500);
    gotoxy(1,27);cout << wawe3 << '\r' << flush;
    Sleep(500);
    i++;
}
```

Y obtengo algo así que es lo que buscaba, una animación pequeña:
https://i.gyazo.com/1b07a224c201f88636686e604082a5d4.mp4
[image: ANIMACION]